# TeeChart package introducing Invalid Typecast in Delphi when GetIt Package Manager is launched

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10.2-tokyo

We're using TeeChart Pro v2012.07.121105 32bit VCL and just upgraded to Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3.  We maintain our own packages and haven't upgraded TeeChart in a while, so I'm hoping someone here can give me some advice.

When our TeeChart package is enabled in the Delphi IDE, launching GetIt Package Manager from the Tools menu causes an Invalid Typecast exception to appear before the GetIt dialog appears. Once the error dialog is closed, GetIt does appear but contains no packages.

If I disable our TeeChart package, the Invalid Typecast no longer occurs and GetIt launches as expected.  With all of our packages disabled, enabling TeeChart is the only one that introduces the Invalid Typecast.

Does anyone know of changes or fixes in TeeChart since 2012 that are related to the integration with the Delphi IDE integration?

Thanks

Comment: I think it should be better if you report this to Embarcadero becouse there is a great chance that the problem actually lies somewhere in Getit Package Manager. The reason I suspect this is becouse othervise you should be getting similar error whenever you try to compile any application that is using your TeeChart components.

Comment: I can't remember any error on GetIt Package Manager, and I can't find a fix referring it in the main TeeChart repo. As you'll understand, Steema Software can't support so old and modified packages. If you can't upgrade your TeeChart version, as @SilverWarior says, you could check with Embarcadero if they can do something at their side.

Comment: My current suspicion is that our version of TeeChart is defining a type that has a name conflict with a type defined in the GetIt Package Manager source. When our TeeChart package is loaded, the type in TeeChart is taking precedence.  I'm hopeful this will jog the memory for David or someone else at Steema and it will be an easy solution to rename the conflicting type in TeeChart. Unfortunately, I don't know the name of the type causing the Invalid Typecast.

Comment: @JonRobertson Without the name of the type that is causing the problem and no access to your modified TeeChart source code I'm afraid none of us can help as we would only be guessing of what might be the problem. So please edit your question and add that information to it.

Comment: Our changes only cleanup hints and warnings. We have not upgraded because we haven't had a reason to and we avoid the risk of upgrading third-party libraries. The type name conflict must one originally implemented by TeeChart and likely changed by TeeChart in newer versions to resolve this specific issue. If I knew the name of the type that was in conflict, we would have changed it ourselves and I would not have posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conflict turned out to be the TGifImage, defined in our TeeChart source in Sources\GIFImage.pas. That class is not compatible with the TGifImage class used by the IDE, yet the TeeChart class was being used by an "as" cast in the GetIt source code.

Renaming the TGifImage class used by TeeChart solved the issue.